# Orderby with menu_order and title

Tags: order

Since Wordpress native order system is a little dumb (ie: 1 banana, 10 bananas, 2 bananas,...)

I needed to add a plugin that let me set the order for numerical titles. The thing is that when I set the `orderby=` with `menu_order title`, the menu is ordered like I've set them in the backend. But for those that their order is set to 0... I would like to fallback to the `orderby=title`.

So in short, I would like that the `orderby=menu_order title` fallback to title if the order are set to 0.

Plugin link for menu order : http://wordpress.org/plugins/term-menu-order/

Comment: MySQL does not easily do "natural" sorting, but what is the question? You are looking for a different plugin? You are trying to hack the plugin from that link?

Comment: I'm trying to be able to sort numeric title in correct order. Since it take it like a string.... seems that i'm a little screwed.

Comment: 01 banana, 02 bananas, 10 bananas doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not do "natural" sorting natively, though [there are attempts to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql).

I have no idea how that plugin you mention works but sorting by `menu_order` with a `post_title` fallback is trivial.

```
add_action(
  'pre_get_posts',
  function ($qry) {
    if ($qry->is_main_query()) {
      $qry->set('orderby','menu_order title');
    }
  }
);
```

Of course, that gets `menu_order` equal 0 at the top of the sort, and I don't think that is what you want.

Like MySQL, `WP_Query` does not have a "natural sort" feature but if what you want is to order by `menu_order` where that `menu_order` is greater than 0, and otherwise by title, which is what I think you want (at at least on point in the question), you can do that with a filter.

```
add_action(
  'posts_orderby',
  function ($orderby,$post) {
    global $wpdb;
    return " IF({$wpdb->posts}.menu_order > 0, {$wpdb->posts}.menu_order {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, {$wpdb->posts}.post_title) ";
  },
  10,2
);
```

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. *Caveat emptor*. No refunds.

You could use a similar filter to try to implement a true natural sort but I don't have time to write, test, and debug that.